# how to alert for delivery report for mail() in php when email id not exist

Tags: php, email

```
<?php

    $sub="test";
    $msg="testing mail code";
    $to1="a......k@gmail.com"; //my active gmail id..i can receive mail here with same code.
    $to2="xyz@abc.com";//i set this invalid id dont get mail with same code because id not existed.

    $to=$to1.','.$to2;

    if(mail($to, $sub, $msg))
    {
        ?>
            <script >
                alert('Message Sent..!!!!');
            </script>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
            <script >
                alert('Oooooooop...... Message not Sent..!!!!');
            </script>
        <?php
    }

    ?>
```

In this given code i having 2 email ids first one is valid and active and another one is guessed id that is not valid and not exist any where .now when i m sending mail with this code it shows me message like message sent..!!!. i know that second email id is wrong so second id cant get that mail,so how i can alert when some ids like second id. which cant get id or which ids are not valid.

Comment: You can't know that immediately just after using mail() function. It sends email, that's all. Only email server can say if that email delivered or not, but this information is not available on the php side.

Comment: check this link http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/141944/check-if-email-address-is-correct-without-sending-email

Comment: thaks hast ... is there any other for solving this problem?

Comment: is it possible with javascript or jquery?

Comment: Is it possible with Disposition-Notification-To?

Comment: or can i use Return-Receipt-TO with my code ?please ans thanks.

Comment: i tried both but not work.  :-( :-( :-( please help...

Answer (score 0):

i have no enough reputation to comment thats why i am posting the answer
you have to check that email id is exists or not by a class of smtp

i think this link will be useful to you

https://code.google.com/p/php-smtp-email-validation/

Answer (score 0):

```
try it

    $sub="test";
    $msg="testing mail code";
    $to1="a......k@gmail.com"; //my active gmail id..i can receive mail here with same code.
    $to2="xyz@abc.com";//i set this invalid id dont get mail with same code because id not existed.


    $n = 2; /// number of emails id 
    for($i=1; $i==$n; $i++)
    {
        $element = $to.$i;
        if(!isValidEmail($element))
        {
            echo "<script>alert('Oooooooop...... Message not Sent..!!!!')</script>";
        }
        else
        {
            if(mail($element, $sub, $msg))
            {
                ?>
                    <script >
                        alert('Message Sent..!!!!');
                    </script>
                <?php
            }
            else
            {
                ?>
                    <script >
                        alert('Oooooooop...... Message not Sent..!!!!');
                    </script>
                <?php
            }
        }
    }

    function isValidEmail($element) {
  return preg_match ("/^[a-z0-9_\+-]+(\.[a-z0-9_\+-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*\.([a-z]{2,4})$/", $element);
}
```

Comment: i don't want to check the id is valid or not but just want to know whom i sent the mail() are delivered successfully or not .is it possible.

Comment: Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE otherwise.

    It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination.

Comment: here i use two ids from that both one is right and another one is wrong .it returns true for that both ids.so how i can get which mail id is wrong when i ll use bulk mail in php mail().thats why i need the delivery report for sent and not sent mail.